React Native Android APP crashed while changing seeting of phone like toggle full screen model option on and off
Any one please guide me I have created app using react native cli and that application is crashed while I do turn off full screen mode to button and vise versa. and I don't get any error log.
Turning fullscreen mode on or off in my application should not cause any crashes.

You mean get around (https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079644?hl=en)?
Did the app crash just once and you can open it again and its working again or crash it again ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm finding apps are crashing when trying to rotate to landscape mode.
